# Fuzzy button text in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button

I've got a basic image input button:

```
<input type="image" class="no-border" name="submit" src="images/buttons/schedule-by-phone.png" onclick="document.pressed='scheduleByPhone'"/>
```

on my website http://www.alohamassagekauai.com/

It looks Great in Firefox & Chrome, but is all blurry in IE. Can someone please tell me why + whether there's anything I can do about it?

Thank-you!
Debbie

Comment: Can I get a screen shot of the difference you're seeing, as it's perfectly sharp for me.

Answer (score -1):

The input type="image" sends the X and Y coordinates of the click that activated the image button.  Choose the right image with blank background. Or may be u should check CSS class.